# 2 airport extremes, one extends the main network but doesn't provide internet over wired ethernet connection

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have 2 apple airport extreme base stations, one is wired in to the modem the other is setup to extend the network of the first.

I want to be able to plug computer into via ethernet into the airport set up as the extender, but it doesn’t read any internet connection.

Any ideas?

For context both base stations are configured with the same SSID and password

The 2nd extreme is not currently in bridge mode, (I tried that but no dice) and in airport utility on the "Wireless" tab I have "Network Mode" set to "Extend a wireless network"

When I have that option selected the "Network" tab in airport utility is completely grayed out.

Comment: Is the second extreme in bridge mode? Or is that the sort of answer you seek?

Comment: It's not currently in bridge mode, I tried that but no dice. I'll update answer to add that. For the 2nd extreme, in airport utility on the "Wireless" tab I have "Network Mode" set to "Extend a wireless network"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time.

1. Connect any of the normal Ethernet from the main station to the source Ethernet on the second station.
2. Set the second to bridge mode
3. Have each broadcast the same network, don’t extend, just set up the same or different SSID / network names to suit your preferences.

Having both create a wireless network works best for me. Until such point you get newer hardware like UniFi Dream Machine (or pro) or perhaps another ubiquiti line or like product.

Comment: Is there a way to have the 2nd station connect to the first wirelessly?

Comment: @Whoaa512 I don’t recommend that, but yes you can extend wirelessly. My answer might not be optimal if you can not use wired backhaul. That gets full gigabit speeds and maximum wireless coverage and speed. Wireless backhaul is lossy and slower.

Comment: @bmike when in bridge mode my AirPort Extreme doesn't show any wireless clients connected to it. They only show as connected to the main AirPort Time Capsule that I have. Is this expected? Is there a way to tell what devices are actually connected to the router that is in bridge mode?

Comment: Yes, I believe that’s what I saw. To tell if a client connects to one or the other, look at the BSSID on the client - both airports will have different ID. I’ve retired all that gear except for the cabin - the home/office has https://store.ui.com/products/udm-us and I’ll order the new dream machine pro for home and move the older DM to the cabin next trip up north.